# Бойцовый или бойцовский - как правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, прилагательные

*...давайте выясним, какая собака называется **бойцовой** и почему?*
[**Породы собак**](https://doggy-puppy.ru/45-boycovskie-sobaki-foto-cena-i-osobennosti.html)

*Ветеринары утверждают, что покалеченных **бойцовских** собак выбрасывают на улицу.*
[**Собачьи бои**](https://www.pressreader.com/russia/moskovski-komsomolets/20170526/281479276362081)

А как правильно: **бойцовый** или **бойцовский** (пёс, петух, навык, клуб, спорт...)?

Answer (score 4):

**Бойцовые** собаки (собаки бойцовых пород) или петухи проявляют выработанные у них дрессировкой **бойцовские** качества, выступая  качестве **бойцов** в состязаниях своих хозяев на предмет того, чей питомец сильнее в **бою** с себе подобными.

**Боец** — тот, кто вступает бой и "бьётся";

**бойцовый** — выступающий в качестве бойца (*только об особи*);

**бойцовский** — свойственный бойцу или предназначенный для использования бойцом.

Comment: Получается, что автор статьи "Собачьи бои..." - на всем ее протяжении  - ошибается,  называя собак бойцовскими? Это ведь все-таки "МК"!

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова МК? Тогда можете не сомневаться, что ошибается. ))) У вас странное представление об авторитетности изданий. Единственное, что может его оправдывать - укоренившийся профессионализм собачников, если такое есть. Но - не сталкивался. Максимум как синонимы.

Comment: Ой! - как хорошо, что Вы здесь. Там у Вас - в "световом годе/году" - в падежах  поправьте, пожалуйста, и в 19017 году, и еще где-то... Я не посмела.

Answer (score 3):

**БОЙЦОВЫЙ,**  ◊ Бойцовые петухи. Петухи с плотным мускулистым телом, выращенные в особых условиях и предназначенные для петушиных боёв.

**БОЙЦОВСКИЙ**,  1. к Боец. Б-ое снаряжение. 2. Наполненный настойчивостью, умением бороться до конца; боевой. Б. характер, темперамент. Б-ие качества. Б-ая хватка.

Из этого следует, что **правильно: бойцовая собака (если есть такие)**, а вот характер у собаки должен быть бойцовским.

**Обсуждение  в Сети** (есть ли вообще такая порода): Бойцовая порода одна. Это питбультерьер. И это прописано не в стандарте, а в комментариях американского кеннел-клуба. [ЧТО ЗНАЧИТ БОЙЦОВАЯ СОБАКА? | Ответы Mail.Ru](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/56915905)

Comment: А как же быть с таким примером: "БОЙЦОВЫМ ХАРАКТЕРОМ в семье выделялась тетка Некрасова ― Софья Николаевна Мотовилова". Владимир Потресов, «Возвращения Некрасова», 2004 г. https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9

Comment: Давайте будем его считать разговорно-стилевым  вариантом ввиду неточности грамматической формы. Суффикс ОВ(ый) используется преимущественно при образовании  прилагательных от  неодушевленных предметов (береза - березовый) и животных (бобер - бобровый), гораздо реже используются сущ. со значением лица (писец - писцовый). Так, в  Нацкорпусе  всё больше говорится о бойцовых петухах, и есть пара примеров "бойцовый старикан" и  "бойцовый человек", явно в ироническом стиле, как и у тетки Некрасова.

Answer (score 0):

По логике - "бойцовые" - те которые сами дерутся, "бойцовские" - те, которые принадлежат неким бойцам или соотносятся с ними. 
То есть куры и собаки - ***бойцовые***.

Беда в том, что в подобных случаях логика и внутренняя лингвистическая правильность отступает перед традицией.
Но в отношении собак это пока что не произошло.
Порода - бойцовая.

А бойцовский - это безотносительно к породе, те, например, которых бойцы прикормили.

Comment: Извините, наверное, бойцовский - тот,  которого прикормили.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова ну да, конечно, спасибо. Извините, не в лучшей форме  сегодня, мышей не ловлю. Впрочем, Alex_ander, все то же самое сказал - и без ошибок ))).